# How to make less error prone code while getting user Input CPP

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, user-input

As we can't trust user input, how we can make the below code more fault tolerant and make less chance of crash on the event of bad input. Please also let me know if any error handling already done in following code is wrong. Thankyou.

```
int main()
{
    //Getting number of products
    int noOfInput; 
    std::cin >> noOfInput;
    std::string line; 
    std::vector<itemInfo> itemsVec;
    for (auto i=0;i<noOfInput;i++)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin>>std::ws, line);
        // Check for failed extraction
        if (!std::cin)
        {
            std::cin.clear(); // put us back in 'normal' operation mode
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // and remove the bad input
            std::cout<< "Oops, that input is invalid.  Please try again.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                itemInfo item;
                // Parse the quantity
                auto start = line.find_first_not_of(" \t");
                auto stop = line.find_first_of(" \t", start);
                item.quantity = std::stoi(line.substr(start, stop - start));
                // Parse the name            
                start = line.find_first_not_of(" \t", stop + 1);
                stop = line.find(" at ", start);
                item.name = line.substr(start, stop - start);
                // Parse the price
                start = line.find_first_not_of(" \t", stop + 4);
                item.actualPrice = std::stod(line.substr(start)); 
                itemsVec.push_back(item);
            }
            catch (const std::logic_error & ex)
            {
                std::cout <<"Logic Error:"<< ex.what()<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Start here: `std::cin >> noOfInput;` ... What happens if the user enters `Bob`?

Comment: You need to check if `std::cin` fails if you give a non-integer `noOfInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic guidelines.

I never `cin >> number`. Never. I always use `getline` and parse the string myself.

You can write methods like `isAllDigits(const std::string &)` to do some validation. And, of course, check that the line isn't empty.

Other useful functions: `trim`, `trimLeft` and `trimRight` to trim whitespace from the front/back of your input.

Using these methods, to read a number, `getline` to read the line, use the trim methods, check for non-empty, use `isAllDigits` to verify they didn't enter garbage, and then, and only then, stoi.

For the rest of your parsing -- you aren't checking that there's more data. If they enter empty strings, for instance, you're happily parsing away but you're almost guaranteed to get string::npos for some of those finders.

It's worth writing a method that splits your input string by whitespace into a vector of strings. This makes the rest of your parsing a lot easier. You can decide if two spaces means an empty slot or not. If you do that, then parsing into bits is just a matter of grabbing `vec[0]`, `vec[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thankyou all for the valuable inputs, I will work on it.